# Go Lambda throwing error with every possible combination of Amazon Linux runtime while building it with CDK

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, aws-lambda, aws-cdk

I've encountered a problem while working with GO CDK from AWS. I've wanted to make a rest API with lambda that uses custom AL2 runtime due to deprecation of GOLANG runtime.

I've tried a few solutions, but none of them really work. They all throw the same error in CloudWatch when I try to cURL (through command line or Insomnia) the API to which this Lambda is attached:

```
Error: fork/exec /var/task/bootstrap: exec format error Runtime.InvalidEntrypoint
```

For a context and further debuging:

- I'm running MacOS Sonoma
- My file structure goes like this (where i'm creating cdk stack in aws-lambda-go.go and implementing lambda in lambdas/main.go):
  [file structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3zq8a.png)

First thing that I've tried was copy-paste same code from AWS compute blog about migration from the Go1.x runtime to the custom runtime on Amazon Linux 2 ([AWS blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/migrating-aws-lambda-functions-from-the-go1-x-runtime-to-the-custom-runtime-on-amazon-linux-2/)):

```
awslambda.NewFunction(stack, jsii.String("HelloHandler"), &awslambda.FunctionProps{
    Code:         awslambda.Code_FromAsset(jsii.String("lambdas"), nil),
    Runtime:      awslambda.Runtime_PROVIDED_AL2(),
    Handler:      jsii.String("bootstrap"),
    Architecture: awslambda.Architecture_ARM_64(),
})
```

Second thing was coping people's code. I've searched for "awslambda.Runtime_PROVIDED_AL" in github and tried all different possible combinations of what people were using in theirs projects. For example I've tried switching architectures, changing Amazon Linux runtimes from 2 to 2023, changing the location of where it gets code from to zip from pure folder location ("lambdas" -> "lambdas/bootstrap.zip"), and tried zipping and building with different flags like sugested here [go-on-aws](https://www.go-on-aws.com/lambda-go/lambda_function/simple-lambda-custom/) (the primary command for building which i used was GOARCH=amd64 GOOS=linux go build -o bootstrap main.go but i've also tried with CGO_ENABLED=0).

Does anywone have any idea what could be the cause of this bug?

Edit: for better explanation of a problem I link a github repo with whole code, it's really small and not hard to understand: https://github.com/Jakub-Ignatowicz/GoCDKProblem

Comment: Have you tried the `GoFunction` construct from the [github.com/aws/aws-cdk-go/awscdklambdagoalpha/v2](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/aws/aws-cdk-go/awscdklambdagoalpha/v2) module?

Comment: @fedonev Hi, thanks for your answer. Unfortunately no, i tried GoFunction now as you sugested and still the same problem accures. My implementation of it looks like this: ` MyFunction := awscdklambdagoalpha.NewGoFunction(stack, jsii.String("MyLambda"), &awscdklambdagoalpha.GoFunctionProps{
  Entry: jsii.String("lambdas"),
 })
`

Answer (score 0):

After 3 days of debuging it turns out inner folder's (lambdas) main.go file was using package lambdas but should use package main. Make sure that your lambdas use main package if same problem occurs for You.